# Vue.js, composition API, "Mixins" and life-cycle hooks

Tags: vue.js, hook, mixins, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I've been looking all around (and I couldn't find) an answer for the following.

In Vue 2.x, you could use mixins for life-cycle hooks, i.e., for instance: I could create a Mixins.js with

```
export default {
  created() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

and then, in a component, do the following:

```
import mixins from "../misc/mixins";

export default {
  name: "My component",
  mixins: [mixins],
  created() {
    console.log('Another test');
  }
}
```

And if I ran "My component", I would get in the console both "Another test" and "test". I cannot find the way of doing something similar with the Composition API (of course, I can execute inside "onMounted" a functions that I imported from another file, but that's not that elegant).

Is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With Composition API you have to import lifecycles you need. Docs with list: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html

*Component.vue*

```
<script>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props) {
    console.log('CREATED')
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('MOUNTED')
    });

    return {};
  },
}
</script>
```

Note that there is no `onCreated()`. From docs:

> Because setup is run around the beforeCreate and created lifecycle hooks, you do not need to explicitly define them. In other words, any code that would be written inside those hooks should be written directly in the setup function.

### But what about using this as Mixins alternative?

Now if you want you can simply extract this to separate file, often called composable.

*demoLifehooks.js*

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

export default () => {
  console.log('Created')
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('Mounted')
  })
}
```

Now simply import it and execute.

*Component.vue*

```
<script>
import useDemoLifecycles from './demoLifecycles.js'

export default {
  setup(props) {
    useDemoLifecycles()

    return {};
  },
}
</script>
```

or even shorter thanks to [new script setup syntax.](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md)

```
<script setup>
import useDemoLifecycles from './demoLifecycles.js'
useDemoLifecycles()
</script>
```

Log in console:

> Created
> Mounted

[**Live example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kare-5ndrk?file=/src/App.vue)

Naming it as `useSomething` is just convention. It will be not a bad idea to force it by exporting not default function but named one:

```
export const useDemoLifecycles = () => { console.log('code here') }
```

and then

```
import { useDemoLifecycles } from './demoLifecycles'
```

Also, if you want refs or other data from that file, it will be

```
const { a, b } = useDemoLifecycles()
```

**Notice that actually in my examples there is not much Vue's "magic", like it was with Mixins. This is pretty much pure JS stuff and not Vue specific code. So it is actually simpler than old Options API + Mixins.**

Comment: Thank you so much! Great and detailed answer!